# Facebook logins only in Editor or Development Build(Unity 3D)

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a problem with the Facebook SDK. It works fine in Editor and in apk(if i check the development build option in Unity), but on release build it doesn't work.

**Here is my code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Facebook.Unity;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;

public class FBManager : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]private Text FBErrorText;

    public RawImage FBProfilePicture;
    public Image DefaultAvatar;

    public Text UsernameText;
    public Text WelcomeMessage;

    public Button FacebookButton;

    private Color fbProfilePictureColor;
    private Color defaultAvatarColor;

    private string getData;
    private string FBUserName;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (!FB.IsInitialized) 
        {   FBErrorText.text = "fb not ini, initializing";
            FB.Init(InitCallBack, OnHideUnity);
            FBErrorText.text = "called fb.init";
        }
        else
        {   FBErrorText.text += "initialized";
            FB.ActivateApp();
            FBErrorText.text += "called fb.activateApp";
        }

        fbProfilePictureColor = FBProfilePicture.color;
        defaultAvatarColor = DefaultAvatar.color;

        fbProfilePictureColor.a = 0f;
        FBProfilePicture.color = fbProfilePictureColor;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine (FbLoginWait ());
    }

    IEnumerator FbLoginWait()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil (()=> FB.IsInitialized);

        FBLogin ();
    }
    //auto logare

    private void InitCallBack()
    {
        if (FB.IsInitialized) 
        {
            //UsernameText.text = "Initialized FB SDK";
            FBErrorText.text = "fb is initialized";
            FB.ActivateApp ();
            FBErrorText.text = "fb activated app";
        } 
        else 
        {
            FBErrorText.text = "Failed to initialize the Facebook SDK";
            Debug.Log ("Failed to initialize the Facebook SDK");
        }
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        if (!isGameShown) 
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;     
        } 
        else 
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }

    private void HandleLoginFB(bool IsLogged)
    {
        if (IsLogged) 
        {
            FBErrorText.text = "user logged in";
            Debug.Log ("User logged in");
        }
        else 
        {
            FBErrorText.text = "user cancelled login";
            Debug.Log ("User cancelled login");
        }
    }

    private void AuthCallback(IResult result)
    {
        FBErrorText.text = "called authcallback";
        HandleLoginFB (FB.IsLoggedIn);
        FBErrorText.text = "handling fb";

        if (FB.IsLoggedIn) 
        {
            var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
            Debug.Log (aToken.UserId);
            foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
                Debug.Log (perm);
            }

            FB.API ("/me/picture?type=square&height=50&width=50", HttpMethod.GET, UpdateProfileImage);
            FB.API ("me?fields=name", HttpMethod.GET, GetUsername);

            FBErrorText.text = "fb is logged in";
        } 
        else 
        {
            FBErrorText.text = "fb is not logged in";
        }
    }

    public void FBLogin()
    {
        FBErrorText.text = "called fblogin";
        List<string> perms = new List<string> () { "public_profile, email", "user_friends" };
        FBErrorText.text = "created perms";
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (perms, AuthCallback);
        FBErrorText.text = "ended fblogin";
    }

    private void UpdateProfileImage(IGraphResult result) 
    {
        if(result.Texture != null) 
        {
            FBProfilePicture.texture = result.Texture;

            defaultAvatarColor.a = 0f;
            fbProfilePictureColor.a = 255f;

            DefaultAvatar.color = defaultAvatarColor;
            FBProfilePicture.color = fbProfilePictureColor;
        }
    }

    private void GetUsername(IGraphResult result)
    {
        FBUserName = result.ResultDictionary ["name"].ToString ();
        UsernameText.text = FBUserName;

        WelcomeMessage.text = FBUserName + "'s NET WORTH";
    }
}
```

(or the same code here https://hastebin.com/osatiketij.cs)

The last error text on the screen which appears is : "created perms", so right before the FB.LogInWithReadPermissions method is called, no error text appears after that, but no login also.

Any idea what it might be ?

Comment: Have you added the correct permissions in the android manifest?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. I don't use Android Studio, so I didn't modify or look into Android Manifest. I also have 2 Android Manifests(probably because I also have Google Play Plugin Installed). Can you tell me what permissions I should write?

Comment: Check that you have this in the manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. Also, if you have two manifest, Unity will try to merge them. You should open the APK with an archive exploring app and check that the manifest inside still has this line

Comment: I eventually used Android Studio to see with the Logcat why it doesn't work, and it was "missing" a class.
For anyone coming here, I fixed it by adding "-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}" to my proguard-user file.

Comment: What you can do now is post your last comment as an answer. In two days, you'll be able to mark is as approved (there is a delay since it is your own answer). This will allow other people to see that this question has a working answer when searchin the site. Also you might get upvotes if it helps people

Answer (score 2):

For everyone coming to this thread : how I manage to fix this was by using Android Studio to see with the Logcat why it doesn't work, and it was "missing" a class. For anyone coming here, I fixed it by adding "-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}" to my proguard-user file.